# SSRS 2005 Deal with Null return value - 0 rather than #Error

Tags: reporting-services

As an SSRS 2005 neophyte, I'm unclear how to accomplish this, and have been unsuccessful incorporating the suggestions of other answers offered here into my specific situation.

Scenario:
I'm calculating the average age of employees by department, gender, etc.  In some cases there is nothing to calculate, and in such cases I would prefer to return a zero.  In its current form, my expression returns #Error.

The expression:

```
=Int(Avg(IIF(Fields!CustGender.Value = "F", CDec(Fields!Age.Value),Nothing),"ReportDataset"))
```

What is the proper syntax/logic to get that expression to return 0 of there are no Female employees in that department?  If I change that "Nothing" to a zero, won't that throw off the Avg function's calculation?

Comment: SSRS has come a very long way since 2005. If it's an option, go for the upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried this, but I think if you manually calculate the average it should work. Sum / Count:

```
=Int( SUM(
    IIF(
      Fields!CustGender.Value = "F",
      CDec(Fields!Age.Value),
      0
    ),"ReportDataset")
    / IIF(COUNT(
    IIF(
      Fields!CustGender.Value = "F",
      1,
      0
    ),"ReportDataset") = 0, 1,
    COUNT(
    IIF(
      Fields!CustGender.Value = "F",
      1,
      0
    ),"ReportDataset"))
    )
```

Of course this will throw an error if there are zero "F" records.

Comment: Jamie, thank you for taking a shot at this.  The code you have offered is showing a syntax error.  I've tried tinkering with it and can't get the error to disappear.  I see what you're trying to do, but I don't see where it solves the initial problem.  The Avg function is working just fine, but it has issues where (as you said) no "F" records are returned.  In such a case, I get the #Error message.

Comment: New thought: Perhaps I can combine your "Count" idea with an IIF that says "if the count is zero, return 0, otherwise do the Avg.  I'll try that when I get some time to work on this.

Comment: fixed the syntax (couple of bad parens.) and added an additional IIF to handle the division when no "F" records exist. (I thought your initial was never returning good data: I thought that came from including `nothing`s in the average.

Comment: Whoa!  Okay. that's progress.  I need to walk through what you're doing so I can wrap my mind around it.  Interestingly, I get the zero in some cases and the #Error in others.  I'll need to study this and see why I get the error now.  Clearly, your approach has resolve the issue where Zero should be returned.  Thanks Jamie!